# ncurses how to use setcchar function

Tags: c++, ncurses

Currently using WSL2, C++20, `-lpanelw -lncursesw`, `#define NCURSES_WIDECHAR 1`, `#include <panel.h>`.

I'm trying to figure out how to create `cchar_t` types using the `setcchar()` function. The function requires a location to store the `cchar_t` struct specified in the parameter `const cchar_t *wcval`.

I couldn't find any tutorials on this, so I tried a couple of approaches, but they all produced errors.

```
cchar_t* ptr;
setcchar(ptr, L"", 0, 0, nullptr);
```

```
cchar_t* ptr {NULL};
setcchar(ptr, L"", 0, 0, nullptr);
```

```
cchar_t* ptr {nullptr};
setcchar(ptr, L"", 0, 0, nullptr);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem through this approach:

```
cchar_t ptr;
setcchar(&ptr, L"", 0, 0, nullptr);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want an explanation here it is:
You have to have actual memory space to store the value, when you pass in just the pointer you have only allocated enough memory to hold that pointer with that pointer containing garbage. The setcchar function goes to the position of that pointer and stores the value there, which doesn't exist (its garbage). Following a trash pointer will probably lead to either undefined behaviour or a segfault, since you would be going to some random position in memory and trying to store your value there.
That's why you must allocate a cchar_t, and pass a pointer to that to the function.